# Pear  location on mac osx lion xampp

Tags: xampp, pear

From my phpinfo, I am seeing that pear is configured in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear location. But when I type pear command at terminal from  /Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear location,  it returns the error:" Could not open input file: /usr/lib/php/pearcmd.php"

Why it is going to /usr/lib... ?

I can not get why this happening.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this:

```
$ cd /usr/lib/php
$ sudo php install-pear-nozlib.phar
```